# In Xamarin using masterdetail how do you detect a page change?

Tags: c#, xamarin

When you have a Xamarin Master/Detail app. How can you detect when the detail pages changes

Basically, when you select a new page I want to be able to detect the change and get the old page to save its data.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to override the OnDisappearing method of the page.

Example:

```
 public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
 {
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
       //write your logic here
    }
 }
```

Comment: Oh wow. I'm sure I tried that. But then my solution got corrupted so I had to start again and now it works